# Crontab para de funcionar quando chega conexão com Oracle em PHP

Tags: php, oracle, cron

Estou tentando executar uma rotina pelo crontab, porém ele trava na conexão com o Banco de Dados. Mas se eu executar o arquivo normalmente como:

```
php /var/www/html/pasta/teste.php
```

Ele me retorna os dados normalmente:

[image: Resultado]

Esse é o meu crontab:

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/pasta/teste.php >> /var/log/teste.log
```

Esse é meu arquivo php:

```
<?php
echo 'Iniciou..  ';

try{
    echo 'Vai conectar?..   ';

    $connection = oci_connect('user' , 'password', 'HOST/DB');

    echo 'Conectou..    ';
} catch (PDOException $e)
{
    $mensagem .= "   Erro: " . $e->getMessage();
    echo $mensagem;
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tabela where rownum <= 2";
$querySQL = oci_parse($connection, $sql);
oci_execute($querySQL);
oci_fetch_all($querySQL, $stmt);

foreach($stmt as $row)
{ 
    var_dump($row) ;
    exit;
}
?>
```

O resultado do crontab fica assim (/var/log/teste.log):

```
Iniciou..  Vai conectar?..
```

Versão do SO:

```
VERSION="18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS"                                                                                        
VERSION_ID="18.04"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloca as variáveis no crontab:

```
ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/pasta/teste.php >> /var/log/teste_laudo.log
```